# Oracle: Updating table with inner join and union

Tags: sql, oracle

We are migrating our PRODUCTION database from MSSQL to Oracle 11G. Part of this process is to recreate some existing stored procedures from TSQL to Oracle SQL. Being new to Oracle, I have a question on best practice in a specific situation.

Essentially, I have a table that summarizes data from a sales transaction table. The basic layout of the table (F5542HIS) is as follows (* indicates index):

```
 *NSAN8 (sold_to)
 *NSSHAN (ship_to)
 *NSMCU (sold_from)
 *NSITM (item)
 *NSCTRY (Century)
 *NSYR (year)
 *NSMNTH (month)
 *NSDCTO (Order Type)
 *NSLNTY (Order Line Sales Type)
 NSAEXP (Total Extended Price)
 NSSOQS (Total Units Shipped)
 NSECST (Total Extended Cost)
```

On my first pass of the script, I populate the table with the primary index values (indicated by the * above).

On the second pass, I need to do an update to this table to populate the summation values from my transaction tables. The transaction tables are the F4211 (open orders) and F42119 (order history), so a union is required.

So, I need to do an update based on the following select statement which returns the proper data:

```
 select sum(cast(sdaexp as numeric)) sumaexp, 
        sum(cast(sduorg as numeric)) sumuorg,
        sum(cast(sdecst as numeric)) sumecst
 from PRODDTA.F4211 a inner join proddta.f5542his b 
      on(a.sdan8  = b.nsan8 and 
         a.sdshan = b.nsshan and 
         a.sditm  = b.nsitm and 
         a.sdlnty = b.nslnty and 
         a.sddcto = b.nsdcto and 
         a.sdlnty = b.nslnty and 
         ltrim(rtrim(a.sdmcu)) = ltrim(rtrim(b.nsmcu)) )
 where sdtrdj >= 108001  and 
       sdtrdj <= 108031 and 
 group by sdaexp, sduorg, sdecst 
 UNION 
 select sum(cast(sdaexp as numeric)) sumaexp, 
        sum(cast(sduorg as numeric)) sumuorg,
        sum(cast(sdecst as numeric)) sumecst
 from PRODDTA.F4211 a inner join proddta.f5542his b 
      on(a.sdan8  = b.nsan8 and 
         a.sdshan = b.nsshan and 
         a.sditm  = b.nsitm and 
         a.sddcto = b.nsdcto and 
         a.sdlnty = b.nslnty and 
         ltrim(rtrim(a.sdmcu)) = ltrim(rtrim(b.nsmcu)) )
 where sdivd >= 108001  and 
       sdivd <= 108031 and 
 group by sdaexp, sduorg, sdecst
```

Notice that the SDTRDJ (transaction date) and also the SDIVD (Invoice date) are using the values >= 108001 and <= 108031. These are JULIAN DAYS (not julian dates). It is a strange method of retaining dates, but it works. 108001 = Jan 1, 2008, and 108031 = Jan 31, 2008.

Also, the F5542HIS table will have a WHERE clause on the update for this example where the NSCTRY (Century) = 20, NSYR (Year) = 8, and NSMNTH (Month) = 1. So essentially, the structure could be inthe form:

```
UPDATE f5542HIS
SET nsaexp=sumaexp, nsuorg-sumuorg, nsecst=sumecst from<union>
where nsctry=20 and nsyr=8 and nsmnth=1
```

I have been looking at the SQL `Update` and also the SQL `MERGE` functions. Can someone help me define the best practice for formatting this statement into either an `UPDATE` or `MERGE` that will work here?

Comment: Just a side note: PL/SQL is exclusively used in stored procedures. Unlike SQL Server where everything is "T-SQL", Oracle makes a clear distinction between SQL and PL/SQL.

Comment: confirmed, this script will be part of a stored procedure, i am just trying to work out specific details for the proc

Comment: It's unclear how records from `union` can be matched with records from `f5542HIS` table ? The `union` query can produce many rows, but the resultset produced by `union` has only three columns `sumaexp, sumuorg, sumecst`, one record of `f5542HIS` table cannot be updated with many values (rows) from `union` query, only one row must be selected from the `union`. Please explain.

Comment: This select union has been designed and tested to only return one row for the matching criteria. I can do this with a cursor but should be able to do it in batch mode. The only part that confuses me is the union. This part is perplexing me to no end.